# command line argument from file content with quote

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file containing command line arguments that I would like to pass to another script.

But this file contain element such as `"param 1" param2 param3`.

Let's call the file with arguments `test.tmp` and the script file `script.sh`.

If I do:

```
script.sh -p `cat test.tmp` -other_params 1 2 3
```

The `script.sh` receives after `p`:

1. `"param`
2. `1"`
3. `param2`
4. `param3`

But I would like:

1. `param 1`
2. `param2`
3. `param3`

Any idea?

Small precision: assume that `script.sh` is not modifiable. The solution must take place in the shell.

Comment: In an ideal world, `test.tmp` should be stored in NUL-delimited form -- the *only* syntax which can store all possible values without requiring parsing. (Safely parsing shell quoting without taking security risks, such as permitting expansions, is surprisingly difficult -- unless you're going to pass the job off to something like `xargs`, but even then its behavior isn't _quite_ compatible with actual bash parsing). If you get an opportunity to encourage the folks who wrote `script.sh` to reconsider, I'd suggest doing so.

Comment: The `mapfile -t` approach suggested by Tom is also a reasonable practice, *if* you have a guarantee that your arguments will never need to contain literal newlines.

Comment: BTW, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 and its links (ie. to the WordSplitting and Arguments pages) for some understanding around *why* the default behavior happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***ASSUMPTION:*** `test.tmp` needs to contain a parameter per line with this approach.

You may use xargs with a linefeed delimiter:

```
cat test.tmp | xargs -d '\n' script.sh -p
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I have control over test.tmp, but not script.sh. Thanks

Comment: One caveat: If you have a really long argument list, `xargs` will run `script.sh` multiple times with different subsets of that list, rather than failing outright. In some cases, this may be undesirable.

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap the command in `eval`:

```
eval "script.sh -p `cat test.tmp` -other_params 1 2 3"

$ cat test.tmp 
"params 1" param2 param3

$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
echo $4
echo $5
echo $6

$ eval "./script.sh -p `cat test.tmp` other_params 1 2 3"
-p
params 1
param2
param3
other_params
1
```

Comment: Eww. Please don't do this unless you trust `test.tmp`'s content; if it contains, say, `$(rm -rf .)`, you're in for a bad day.

Comment: Yes, that is a good point in general, but the OP said he has control of `test.tmp` in this case so there is no danger.

Comment: It's one thing to control the format of a file, another thing to control its contents. If I own the script that writes `foo.txt`, but that script's output is written based on inputs it's given at runtime, then unless I take great care my output still can't be trusted to be non-malicious.

Comment: I pull this story out a lot, but I had a former employer that lost TB of backups because they were sloppy in the scripting for their cleanup scripts -- after all, they controlled every program that wrote to that directory, so why worry? Then a new version of one of those programs is written with a buffer overflow that can spew random data into the filenames. A filename gets written with a whitespace-surrounded wildcard in it, and hilarity (not) ensues. The chances of such an error may be low, but the consequences when one *does* happen can be catastrophic; why take unnecessary risks?

Answer (score 2):

Lay out your file like this:

```
param 1
param2
param3
```

then read it into an array like this:

```
mapfile -t params < file
```

then call your script like this:

```
script.sh -p "${params[@]}" -other_params 1 2 3
```

The advantage of this approach is that it only uses built-in bash commands and doesn't require an `eval`.

To do it all in one line, you can use:

```
mapfile -t params < file && script.sh -p "${params[@]}" -other_params 1 2 3
```

i.e. use `&&` to execute the second command if the first one succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` with `Perl` regex:

```
IFS=$'\n'; ./script.sh -p $(grep -woP '((?<=")[^"]*(?="))|([\S]+)' test.tmp)
```

**Example:**

*script.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
echo "$4"
...
```

Output:

```
-p
param 1
param2
param3
...
```

Note: It will change the `IFS` of the current shell (where you are running these commands).

Comment: This does not work for my issue. When expending the value of the $(...) the first parameter will be `"param` and the second will be `1"`. When I need the first parameter to be `param 1`

Comment: This approach sends the (quoted) grep output as the second parameter to `script.sh`, whereas OP expects `param2` and `param3` to be sent as separate args.

Comment: @MarcSimon can you check if this new edit meets your requirement?